# Opening multiple files in text editor with find command

Tags: perl, shell, unix, vim

I am trying to open multiple files in vim from the command line with this command. For some reason I am getting an erro as you will see below.

```
 $ find . -name edit.html.erb  \
     | perl -pi -e 's/^..//'   \
     | perl -pi -e 's/\n$/ /'  \
     | vim
```

When I run it without "| vim" as in this command:

```
 $ find . -name edit.html.erb  \
     | perl -pi -e 's/^..//'   \
     | perl -pi -e 's/\n$/ /'
```

And get this output:

```
 addresses/edit.html.erb claims/edit.html.erb emails/edit.html.erb owners/edit.html.erb packages/edit.html.erb users/edit.html.erb vessels/edit.html.erb voyages/edit.html.erb %
```

I get an error that probably has something to do with that "%" mark at the end of the output.

Here is the output and error:

```
 Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
 Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
 Vim: preserving files...
 Vim: Finished.
```

How can I fix this? Not sure which of the parts is causing the error since I'm a newb, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the `%` your prompt, not part of the output?

Comment: Yes, it is my prompt. (Or at least the same thing occurs when I use sed.) I am trying to open all edit views in a rails project because I need to add something to all of them. Hence, the find to first filter out my choices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing the contents of the files as keyboard input. I presume what you want to do is launch `vim` with the files open. I don't know `vim`, but that's usually achieved by passing the file names as arguments.

In bash, one would use:

```
vim $( find . -name edit.html.erb | perl -pe's/^..//' | perl -pe's/\n$/ /' )
```

(Removed the nonsense use of `-i`.)

Actually, changing the newlines to spaces is useless, and so is removing the leading `./`, so all you need is:

```
vim $( find . -name edit.html.erb )
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets look into the documentation for vim:

```
SYNOPSIS
   vim [options] [file ..]
   vim [options] -
   vim [options] -t tag
   vim [options] -q [errorfile]
```

This tells us that we can specify lots of filenames as command line args, and `-` symbolizes that the "file" will be loaded from STDIN. But this is not the filename, but the buffer contents!

Let your Perl script `exec` into vim with the correct args.

```
exec "vim", @filenames;
```

or similar. This would make your toolchain

```
 $ find . -name edit.html.erb  \
   | perl -pi -e 's/^..//'   \
   | perl -ne 'chomp; push @files, $_; }{ exec "vim", @files'
```

(Are you really sure that you want to remove the first two characters of any filename? That's what `s/^..//` does. Escape the dots to match literal `.`)

Comment: Not exactly familiar with that but I'll try to figure it out! Do you think it can be done from the command line?

Comment: Yes. I don want to remove the first two characters because the output from find is like this: "./path/to/file" and thus won't open. PS. "It works!"

Answer (score 3):

Piping into the standard input of `vim` won't do anything (anything helpful, anyway). You want to pass command line arguments, not input. In `bash`, use backticks or the `$(...)` syntax for this.

```
vim `find . -name edit.html.erb | perl -pe's/^..//' | perl -pe's/\n$/ /'`
vim $(find . -name edit.html.erb | perl -pe's/^..//' | perl -pe's/\n$/ /')
```

(The `-i` option to Perl doesn't do anything here, either. That option is for "in-place" editing of files when you provide file names on the command line.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about the secondary OS: vim

```
:args `find . -name edit.html.erb`
:argadd `find . -name edit.html.js`
```

Or even

```
:args **/edit.html.erb
```

(see also :argdelete, :args, :argdo etc)

(the other answers pretty much beat down the other paths invoking vim with certain filename arguments)